# execute a wrapped jar file within a jar

Tags: java, jvm, wrapper, executable-jar

I am trying to create a wrapper around a runnable .jar file in order to pass parameters for the JVM.
The related code of my wrapper is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      String[] cmdArray = {"java",
        System.getProperty("os.arch").contains("64") ? "-d64" : "",
        "-XX:+AggressiveHeap",       
        "-jar",
        "/lib/A.jar"  //replace with jar name 
            };
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
}
```

The A.jar file is a referenced library (added in build path and class path) in my Wrapper project. Example:

```
 Wrap
   >src
       >org
           >Wrapper.java
   >lib
       >A.jar
```

When I create the second jar file, from the Wrapper project (lets call it B.jar), its content is

```
lib
   >A.jar
org
   >eclipse
          >jdt
             >... (i.e., all the files for the jarinjarloader)
   >Wrapper.class
META-INF
       >MANIFEST.MF
```

My manifest file from the second jar looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: lib/A.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Main-Class: org.Wrapper
```

When I launch the B.jar file, it shows me that the process started, but A.jar file is not called/launched. No error, no exception. The process starts and terminates. Tried to launch it via command line and double-click also.

If I modify the MANIFEST.MF file to

```
Rsrc-Class-Path: A.jar
```

and the element from cmdArray in the main method of the Wrapper.java from

```
"/lib/A.jar" to "A.jar"
```

and I make a copy of A.jar in the folder where my wrapper jar is present (e.g., B.jar), it launches perfectly, calling the second jar.
What am I doing wrong? How am I suppose to pass the class path to an inner jar file?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not strictly speaking an answer to your question, I think I can propose you a better approach in solving your original problem (i.e. adding args to jvm).

[This article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java) discusses how to restart java app preserving jvm, command line and other launch options.

Why this might be interesting to you? Well, tweaking it a bit, what you can do is to get rid of adding wrapper around you main jar and do something like this in your main:

1. check for presence of some command line argument that tells that app is runned with tweaked vm options and:
2. if present - let the app to do it's work
3. in not - restart application, tweaking jvm options as well as passing command line argument referred in step 1

I've done something like this in one of my past projects and it helped to ease build/packaging and debugging compared to wrapped jar approach.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The fact is that the application will be distributed to different clients, different OS' and/or java configurations. Your solution is a pretty elegant way, but I do not now from advance what JVM they are using. It is very annoying that this issue (setting JVM arguments while creating a jar) was not solved, despite the countless demands in the last years. Anyhow, +1 for your suggestion.

Comment: @Marius About the issue with different OS/JVMs you mentioned: You will have exactly the same problem with your wrapper. In fact the only difference I see is that you use use plain `java` command to run your wrapped jar, and in the mentioned article java command is determined from current jvm using `System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java"`. I see no reason why you cannot change this specific piece of code favor of your variant of running if you feel more confident with that.

Comment: BTW: I can confirm that approach with restarting works like a charm for HotSpot on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Well to be honest, I do not really trust the System.getProperty("bla") as I saw that when using System.getProperty("os.arch") or System.getProperty("sun.cpu.isalist") on my machine, which has an intel architecture, it returns me amd64.